# How to find and hide the NSView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsview

**view1.h** file

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSView  *aboutView;
```

In the **view1.m** file created NSView

```
aboutView = [[NSView alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(6, 6, width -12, height -29)];
[aboutView setHidden:YES];
[view addSubview:aboutView];


NSImageView *imgl=[[NSImageView alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, width -12, height -29)];
[imgl setImageAlignment:NSImageAlignBottomLeft];
[imgl setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable];
[imgl setImageScaling:NSImageScaleAxesIndependently];
[imgl setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"yuan"]];
[aboutView addSubview:imgl];
```

NSView in **ButtonController.m** how to find and hide the NSView ?

```
-(void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
    NSView *aboutView = [(view1 *)self.superview.window aboutView];
    [aboutView setHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: Where did you declare "aboutView" (not the property, the actual variable)?

Comment: view1.h declare "aboutView"

Comment: Why do not you write directly as [self.aboutView setHidden:YES] in -(void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent method ?? Coz, you are taking the object right ? @孤魂楚

Comment: I want to click to hide the View .

Comment: Could you explain me clearly ?  @孤魂楚

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
-(void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
    view1 *viewObj=(view1 *)self.superview.window;
    NSView *aboutView = [viewObj aboutView];
    [aboutView setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: ButtonController.m:109:30: Incompatible pointer types initializing 'ViewTitleBarBtn *' with an expression of type 'NSView *'

Comment: It means `ViewTitleBarBtn` (the return type of `aboutView`) is not compatible with `NSView`.  That is an easy error message.

Comment: the problem may be you are not getting the viewobj properly.try self.superview.superview.window